# Writing to csv, 3 variables

Tags: python, csv

I am attempting to write to a .csv file 3 variables: Date, min, max temperatures. I subsituted tmax and tmin with a number since I don't want to repeat the import etc.

Here is my code:

```
import json
import datetime
import time
import csv
import sys

tmin = float(30.3333)
tmax = float(31.4444)

from datetime import datetime

i = datetime.now()
todayD = i.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
minmax = [todayD, tmin, tmax]

with open("C:/Users/anderstn/Desktop/JsonToCsv/"+today+"_MinMax"+".csv", 'w', newline='') as e:
    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(e, fieldnames=["Date", "Min Temp", "Max Temp"])
    dict_writer.writeheader()
    dict_writer.writerows(todayD, tmin, tmax)
```

I have also tried several iterations:

```
dict_writer.writerows(todayD: tmin: tmax)
dict_writer.writerows(todayD | tmin | tmax)
dict_writer.writerows(minmax)
```

Typically the error reads:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/anderstn/Desktop/JsonToCsv/JsonImport.py", line 42, in <module>
    dict_writer.writerows(todayD, tmin, tmax)
TypeError: writerows() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

Cheers,

Comment: have you tried [writerow](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerow) like `dict_writer.writerow(minmax)`?

Comment: dict_writer.writerow() would work for your case.
```data = {}```
```data['date'] = todayD```
```data['min'] = tmin```
```data['max'] = tmax```
```writer.writerow(data)```

Comment: Same error as above Sijan, and Azat I get:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/anderstn/Desktop/JsonToCsv/JsonImport.py", line 42, in <module>
    dict_writer.writerow(minmax)
  File "C:\Users\anderstn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\csv.py", line 155, in writerow
    return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
  File "C:\Users\anderstn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\csv.py", line 148, in _dict_to_list
    wrong_fields = rowdict.keys() - self.fieldnames
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'

For your solution

Comment: You need to send a dict structure as I have modified above. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you don't need to cast floats to floats, just write

```
tmin = 30.3333
tmax = 31.4444
```

[`DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) works with dictionaries (`dict` and its subclasses), also [`writerows`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows) works with lists (or other iterables) of dictionaries, in our case [`writerow`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerow) method is enough, so we need to pass dictionary to `writerow`, not `list` instance.

Finally your sample may look like this

```
import csv

from datetime import datetime

tmin = 30.3333
tmax = 31.4444

i = datetime.now()
todayD = i.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
minmax = [todayD, tmin, tmax]
fields_names = ["Date", "Min Temp", "Max Temp"]
# here we making dictionary from `minmax`
# because `DictWriter` works with dictionaries
data = dict(zip(fields_names, minmax))

# FIXME: here is the problem with name `today`, it is our `todayD` or something else?
with open("C:/Users/anderstn/Desktop/JsonToCsv/" + today + "_MinMax" + ".csv",
          'w', newline='') as e:
    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(e,
                                 fieldnames=fields_names)
    dict_writer.writeheader()
    dict_writer.writerow(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

writerows() expects an iterable, which contains one object per line. Each line should be a list. writerow() also expects an interable, which contains one object per column. e.g.

```
dict_writer.writerow([todayD,tmin,tmax])
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/anderstn/Desktop/JsonToCsv/JsonImport.py", line 42, in <module>
    dict_writer.writerow([todayD, tmin, tmax])
  File "C:\Users\anderstn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\csv.py", line 155, in writerow
    return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
  File "C:\Users\anderstn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\csv.py", line 148, in _dict_to_list
    wrong_fields = rowdict.keys() - self.fieldnames
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'

I receive this error Dan

Comment: My mistake. You're using DictWriter so you should provide a dict object to be written rather than a list. Either that or just use csv.writer()

Answer (score 0):

The method `DictWriter.writerows()` expects a **list of dictionaries**, so you have to put todayD, tmin, tmax in a dictionary with the keys used when creating the `csv.DictWriter` and then put this dictionary in a list.

Also, if you just want to write todayD, tmin, tmax you might use `DictWriter.writerow()` to write a **single dictionary** in a row.

Answer (score 0):

From: – Sijan Bhandari

```
todayD = i.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
minmax = {}
minmax['Date'] = todayD
minmax['Min Temp'] = tmin
minmax['Max Temp'] = tmax



with open("C:/Users/anderstn/Desktop/JsonToCsv/"+today+"_MinMax"+".csv", 'w', newline='') as e:
    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(e, fieldnames=["Date", "Min Temp", "Max Temp"])
    dict_writer.writeheader()
    dict_writer.writerow(minmax)
```

Cheers,